# match values according to index in bash

Tags: bash, indexing

I was wondering if there was an elegant way of doing the following in bash:

I need to check a list for a certain value, lets call it "1". For each entry which I find this value, I need to accumulate a matching string (with same index) in another list, and eventually print it out.

For example:
Lets assume the list of values is `"1 0 1 1 "`

and the list of strings is `"What a wonderful day"`

so the output string would be `"What wonderful day"`

Thanks

Comment: How does the list value associate with the strings? For value "1", how does that tie with a string?

Comment: By its index. If There is "1" in index 0 then the string with index 0 in the string list should be accumulated

Comment: ok thanks. So in the example given wonderful has index 2. Are these lists stored in files?

Comment: No they aren't. They are generated within a script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here my proposed solution:

```
#!/bin/sh
myMatch=1 #This is the value you're looking for
myString="What a wonderful day";
myList=( $myString ) #String to Array conversion
count=0;
for i in $@; do #Iterate over the input parameters
    if [ $i -eq $myMatch ]; then
        echo -n "${myList[$count]} " #use -n to avoid newline and append space as a separator
        count=$(($count+1))
    fi
done
```

So calling the script giving the list of values:

```
$ . myScript.sh 1 0 1 1
```

you have the wanted result.